# How to view a Bug Trends Report in Azure DevOps Server with Inheritance Process Collections

Tags: azure-devops

I'm running Azure DevOps 2019 and I have a collection which uses the new Inheritance model.  This means the SSRS Reporting is not available like it is on the old XML type collections.  Instead Microsoft have switched to using Analytics for reporting.

With the old XML collections we could use SSRS to view a Bug Trends report: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/bug-trends-report?view=azdevserver-2019

Now I need the equivalent for my inheritance collections.  Something which will show the average time from opening an issue to closing it.  I've looked through the dashboard widgets and installed the Analytics marketplace extension.  There seems to be charts for Sprints, but nothing which lets me specifically track the life time of bugs.

Can anyone advise on how to create an alternative to the Bug Trends report with Analytics?

Thanks